# System.ApplicationException when using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

When inserting data in my database with linq to sql i get this exception on SubmitChanges(), yet everything used to work before:

> System.ApplicationException: Member
>   AutoSync failure. For members to be
>   Auto-Synced after insert, the type
>   must either have an auto-generated
>   identity, or a key that is not
>   modified by the database after insert.

Comment: As far as I know, LINQ to SQL (or System.Data.Linq) does not throw ApplicationException exceptions. Are you sure this is a LINQ to SQL problem? Are you hooking other functionality into L2S?

Comment: I was catching the exception using throw new ApplicationException(ex.message); But it is the linq exception that was thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error says, does your table have an identity column on it?  If it does, have you tried to change the value of it before Submitting?

Comment: I was doing multiply submits with starting my application several times. And the rows changed from one process caused problems in my other processes.